# Reading user input and displaying the ASCII equivalent

Tags: c, ascii

I'm writing a program that asks the user to input a number and displays the ASCII equivalent. It also displays the ASCII numbers of the 5 previous numbers and the five next numbers.

here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
displayASCIITABLE(int input);
int main()
{
   int input;
  printf("enter a number:\n");
 
 
displayASCIITABLE(input);
return 0;
}
displayASCIITABLE(int input)

{
    printf("Number    Character\n");
   for(int i=input-5;i<=input+5;i++)
{

  printf("%d         %c\n",i,i);
}

}
```

The code works perfectly but some of the numbers ASCII value is not showing here's an example
[image]

for example, the ASCII value of 7 8 9 10 as shown in the image above

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are probably escape codes, for example 10 is a newline. These types of characters aren't supposed to be shown but affect things like formatting

Comment: do you know how i should fix it

Comment: You can detect whether the character is displayable and if it is not you can output a placeholder character since there's nothing to display

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not all character codes in ASCII are printable. Please, [read about ASCII on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), it will help you.

For instance, only characters from `32` ( , space) to `126` (`~`, tilde) are printable (i.e.: they are displayable on a terminal or in a text file, etc). There are also whitespace characters like `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, and others, that are considered control characters, but they do have some visual effect in a terminal (or in a text file, etc).

NOTE: the strange symbols you see in your terminal are not part of ASCII (intended as US-ASCII), but they are an extension to ASCII (but their codes are platform-dependent, since they rely on which character encoding your terminal has).

TL;DR: you cannot print any integer as it were a character; some character codes are just not displayable.